# Looking for a pre trained neural network for recommendation system using user ratings

Tags: recommendation-engine, transfer-learning, pre-trained-model, cold-start

I'm having a cold start in building a restaurant recommendation system, and I can not find a pre-trained model that I can use directly or through transfer learning

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you created a model save its weights in h5 file .
Then use that h5 file in your algorithm